# External files not linking in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm very new to coding and thus VS Code. I am on a mac.  Whenever I try to link an external file in VS Code to another file it never works.  I understand it has to be a bad file path but I cannot figure it out at all.  I've tried removing files from folders so they're in their own section and this does not work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Number Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Number Guessing Game</h1>
    <button type="button" onclick="runGame()">Start Game</button>
    <script src="/js/number-guessing-game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js file:

```
function runGame() {

    let guessString = '';
    let guessNumber = 0;
    let correct = false;
    let numtries = 0;

    const randomNumber = Math.random() * 100;
    const randomInteger = Math.floor(randomNumber);
    const target = randomInteger + 1;

    // const target = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    do {
        guessString = prompt('I am thinking of a number in the range 1 to 100.\n\nWhat is the number?');
        guessNumber = +guessString;
        numTries += 1;
        correct = checkGuess(guessNumber, target);
    } while (!correct);

    alert('You got it! The number was' + target + '.\n\nIt took you' + numTries + ' tries to guess correctly.');
}

function checkGuess(guessNumber, target){
    let correct = false;
    if (isNaN(guessNumber)) {
        alert('You have not entered a number.\n\nPlease enter a number in the 1-100 range.');
    } else if ((guessNumber < 1) || (guessNumber > 100)) {
        alert('Please enter an integer in the 1-100 range.');
    } else if (guessNumber > target) {
        alert('Your number is too large!');
    } else if (guessNumber < target) {
        alert('Your number is too small!');
    } else {
        correct = true;
    }
}   return correct;
}
```

Here's what file setup looks like:
[image: pic of what file setup looks like]

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the relative path instead of absolute:

```
<script src="js/number-guessing-game.js"></script>
```

Also you have syntax error in js, here is an working example:

```
function runGame() {

    let guessString = '';
    let guessNumber = 0;
    let correct = false;
    let numtries = 0;

    const randomNumber = Math.random() * 100;
    const randomInteger = Math.floor(randomNumber);
    const target = randomInteger + 1;

    // const target = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    do {
        guessString = prompt('I am thinking of a number in the range 1 to 100.\n\nWhat is the number?');
        guessNumber = +guessString;
        numTries += 1;
        correct = checkGuess(guessNumber, target);
    } while (!correct);

    alert('You got it! The number was' + target + '.\n\nIt took you' + numTries + ' tries to guess correctly.');
}

function checkGuess(guessNumber, target) {
    let correct = false;
    if (isNaN(guessNumber)) {
        alert('You have not entered a number.\n\nPlease enter a number in the 1-100 range.');
    } else if ((guessNumber < 1) || (guessNumber > 100)) {
        alert('Please enter an integer in the 1-100 range.');
    } else if (guessNumber > target) {
        alert('Your number is too large!');
    } else if (guessNumber < target) {
        alert('Your number is too small!');
    } else {
        correct = true;
    }


    return correct;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, I do appreciate you taking the time to look over my question. .  I think I've compared what you entered and what I have around 6 times thus far and I can't see a difference.  What am I missing here haha?

Comment: In the JS file, on the last lines, there are two closing brackets, but only one is needed, also the return should be before the last closing bracket.

Comment: In the HTML part, the difference is that the path to the script doesn't start with trailing slash.

Comment: Okay, I must've pasted my code and question before I realized the second bracket was there and had already took it out.  Still does not work for some reason in the html page, took out the / so it starts with js. Nothing.

Comment: You have also to move the return, try copy/paste my code.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by linking to resources about _why_ using a relative path works and an absolute path doesn't work. I'm pretty sure this answer applies since @hurricane42 is (I'm guessing) opening their page via `file://`, but the story could be different if they were, for example, using something like liveserver to serve it, and having appropriately conifgured a root path for the server.